# Override and modify protocols methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I have protocols methods in all my viewControllers that runs exactly the same code, they do things on my viewController. I would like to call them and pass the viewController as a param, instead of override them from subclasses and write the same code again and again. Is that posible? How to do it? 
For example, in the method below, I would like to pass a child viewController as a param, to iterate it, and execute some sentences on it. If I could do that, I wouldn't need to rewrite this code one time and another in every subclass. Is that posible to do?

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //iterate an array of subviews and finds indicator
    NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];

    for (UIView *subview in subviews)
    {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]] && [subview respondsToSelector:@selector(stopAnimating)])
        {
            [subview performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating)];
        }
    }


    CGSize contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize;
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

    float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;

    webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
    webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
    webView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution be to put the code in a common super class then?

Comment: this code I've showed above is from the superclass. But it do things on the view controller, so I have to rewrite it on children viewControllers as I can't pass the child viewController as a param. I'm looking for an alternative for this.

Comment: I don't get it... Why would you not be able to do the thing you want to do on your viewController in your superclass implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have subclasses running the same code then that code belongs in their superclass.  However their superclass doesn't have to be `UIViewController`.

So derive a class from `UIViewController` called `BaseViewController` (or whatever) and implement `webViewDidFinishLoad:` in that superclass, using the code you show in your question, and then derive all your subclasses from `BaseViewController`.  Don't forget to make `BaseViewController` conform to whatever protocols you are dealing with.

If the subclasses do need to add something to the implementation of the `webViewDidLoad:` then implement it in the subclass calling the super class method where ever appropriate:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // Some code here
    [super webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];
    // And/or here
}
```

Comment: the code I showed above is from the superclass, but this code runs on a view controller, that's why I would like to pass it as an argument, then I'd only have to call [super webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView]; from childrens view controllers, so what I would like to do is the equivalent of [super webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView withSelfViewController:(UIViewController*)self];

Comment: I don't understand your point.  If you implement that functionality in a common base class then it's all done for you.

Comment: My problem is that this code do things directly on the viewController from were it runs, so If I call [super webViewDidFinishLoad:] it the child View controller, I need to pass the child view as a param or rewrite the whole code in the childViewController and execute it from there, because this method do things on the view. I'm looking for the equivalent of passing the view as a param, because I can't pass it as param or I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Move the view into `BaseViewController`.  The idea behind my answer is to move all common UI elements and functionality into a common superclass and only have distinct elements/functionality in the subclasses.

Comment: How do I move the view into baseViewController? You mean to use only one viewController, the one from baseViewController class, and use it for all the subclass logic and only use those subclasses to add new logic into this baseViewController?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  However it's not exactly clear to me how the workflow within *Interface Builder* functions with this kind of class hierarchy.  It might not be possible, for example, to add UI elements in the subclass in IB.

Comment: Is there a better or more recomended kind of class hierarchy?

Comment: Thanks a lot For your help!